# Windows Phone Javascript callbacks broken in 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am attempting to troubleshoot some issues with a webbrowser we use in our Windows Phone application. The problem is that our Windows Phone that is running 8.0 receives all of its javascript callbacks fine and loads the webpage happily. When the 8.1 phone runs the application, the web page doesn't load and the javascript callbacks aren't hit.

Relevant code:

```
this.ShowBlocker(true);

        browser = new WebBrowser()
        {
            Name = "browser",
            IsScriptEnabled = true,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch
        };

        browser.ScriptNotify -= this.ScriptNotify;
        browser.ScriptNotify += this.ScriptNotify;
        browser.Navigated -= this.Browser_Navigated;
        browser.Navigated += this.Browser_Navigated;
        browser.NavigationFailed -= this.Browser_NavigationFailed;
        browser.NavigationFailed += this.Browser_NavigationFailed;

        if (browser.Source != this.mapSource.MapUrl)
        {
            browser.Navigate(this.mapSource.MapUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            this.isWebPageLoaded = true;
            this.isJsLoaded = true;
            this.Clear();
            this.JSMap_Loaded();
        }

        this.BrowserContainer.Child = browser;
```

Has something changed in 8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by reformatting the phone. Weird.